# What does "Больше ада" mean?

Tags: значения

[Больше ада](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0) seems to be a meme on the Russian internet, but what does it mean in practice?  The literal translation of "More/better hell" does not seem to explain the context, and the [random comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9585763) that leads me to ask this likens this Richard Gabriel's famous (in IT circles, anyway) "[Worse is Better](http://www.jwz.org/doc/worse-is-better.html)" essay, which also doesn't explain much.

Comment: Its pretty much like "more trash please" or "more bullshit please" sarcastic phrase

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I beleive it is a shortened version of a meme known as "[Адъ и Израиль](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%90%D0%B4%D1%8A_%D0%B8_%D0%98%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C)" which means "total mess". Linked Lurkmore page states that some [network character](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0_%D0%98%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) used this phrase in the same meaning. However [this article](http://www.newsru.co.il/world/14dec2005/grek.html) states that synonymity of Israel and Hell could be taken from some less known church document.

It can be used in the following manner:

> В комментах к статье - просто Ад и Израиль!
>   (The comments to an article are total mess!)

Which indicates that many people were offended by an article or the post, or a flame war began there, etc.

So, when a person sees that the comments (or an article, or a post) can be described as a "total mess" then they can add a sarcastic comment "Больше ада!" which means "Add more insanity! I want more!".

In fact if you google the "ад и израиль" phrase you'll find that it is rather popular (500k search results).

Answer (score 13):

As I understand context in most of cases, usually it is a sort of sarcasm. When you see something very strange and stupid, that can be considered as "ад" (hell), you can say "больше ада" in meaning "Did anyone see something more stupid? Show it to me!"
Also, it can mean sequel of a story. For example, you saw something strange and wrote a news article about that. Next day you saw something worse and wrote another article with header "Больше ада!".

Comment: +1  this phrase is a pure sarcasm with a purpose to highlight the stupidity/ridiculousness of the happening

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but as I understand,  it can be literally translated as (a little ) 'more  OF hell' (on this earth).

Answer (score 1):

This words actually can be translated literally as "More of hell" or better "It's crazy".
It's nature comes from idiom "Ад" ("Hell") - something not from this world, an action from a man or a group of people, which is beyond any logic.
Typically it starts from post "Просто ад" ("Just a hell" or "It's crazy") with description of something or someone crazy behavior, if author or someone from a comments find analogue or a continuation for a post it's adding a comment or a second post "Больше ада" ("More of hell" or "Even crazier").
Example: Post #1 from someone 'It is crazy, I just saw a man fall from the upper floor', then Post #2 'It is even crazier, he had not a scratch, returned to upper floor and FALL AGAIN!'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as a russian, I would understand it as "add more insanity!" or 
"more trash!". I saw some usages, often it is a sarcasm. Like I googled and a saw some blog post, a person complains about bullshit in the news, and at the end he asks to add even more bullshit, more dead people, more hell :D

Answer (score 0):

I often see it in opposition communities, when someone posts news about madness in the Russian leadership, like Mezulina's initiatives or Astakhov's comments about women, people often reply "Больше ада!" = "(Let's have) more hell!" meaning the more insane the Russian authorities become, the sooner their rule will be over.